# Does Ubuntu support 3D monitors?

Tags: monitor, 3d, ubuntu-tv

A couple of manufacturers are coming out with 3D monitors, primarily useful in gaming. It looks to me like they broadly rely on proprietary Windows drivers to work. Am I right?

Are there existing projects to get this kind of support in Linux/Ubuntu? Would this support happen at the kernel level, X.org/Wayland level or drivers?

This is of course vitally important with the advent of 3D-capable TVs and Ubuntu TV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only answer how 3-D playback of movie files is achieved on my system.
I use  LG 2780D passive 3D monitor connected by HDMI to a Geforce 520T.

2 methods

Method 1, not strictly done via Ubuntu, but by the monitor itself.
Play the 3d movie with any media player that plays fullscreen.I use VLC.
Just Use the monitor remote to select 3-D mode according to source.(Side by Side or Top,Bottom etc). Advantage of this method is the quality of the source. Disadvantage is having to switching the monitor back and forth when viewing 3-D  and using the desktop in 2-D.

Method 2 - Use a player that can deliver interleaved 3-D, only one I know of for now is Youtube (in Firefox), using youtube videos.
Using Youtube as source, change the 3-D method to interlaced.
You can now watch 3-D either in the youtube window or expand youtube to fullscreen.
Advantage - no switching modes with the monitor.Disadvantage the variant quality of the source and you are limited to youtube clips.

In general you want to use 1080p for the source movies as the resolution is reduced to view 3-D (using passive).

So for movies at least, no special development/driver is required, just a 3-D capable player.